# Window 7, PHP, Unable to load dynamic libary 'C:\PHP\ext\php_oci8.dll'

Tags: php

I installed PHP in window 7, running simple PHP without issue.
when I want to connect oracle db 11g XE, using `$conn = oci_connect ($user, $pawd, 'localhost/XE');` I get the following errors:

```
Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_oci8.dll' ...
Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll' ...
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect (..);
```

I checked that C:\PHP\ext\php_oci8.dll is there and I changed the following in php.ini file.

```
extension_dir = "C:\PHP\exe";
extension=php_bz2.dll;
extension=php_curl.dll;
extension=php_oci8.dll;
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll;
```

what is the issue behind this?

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: `extension_dir = "C:\PHP\exe";` should be `extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext";`

Comment: sorry, it is c:\PHP\ext.

Answer (score 0):

try to copy the files orannzsbb11.dll , oci.dll and oraociei11.dll to c:\windows\system32